# JSON response returning null

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have followed a tutorial from here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/  but I have come to a problem with the JSON response. It is returning null.
I think it is due to the character encoding as some of the content that is being returned as null includes ° symbols.

The PHP code is:

```
// Check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// Looping through all results

$response["ntmNotices"] = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $ntmRow = array();
    $ntmRow["uploadDate"] = $row["uploadDate"];
    $ntmRow["uploadTime"] = $row["uploadTime"];
    $ntmRow["ntmTitle"] = $row["ntmTitle"];
    $ntmRow["ntmDate"] = $row["ntmDate"];
    $ntmRow["ntmContent"] = $row["ntmContent"];

    // push single row into final response array
    array_push($response["ntmNotices"], $ntmRow);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response    
echo json_encode($response);

} else {
// no rowsfound
$response["success"] = 0;
```

and the response is "ntmContent":null}
ntmContent is what contains the odd characters but they appear fine in the database.

The tutorial doesn't cover issues surrounding character encoding so doesn't prepare for it but how should the $response be handled to accept the odd characters?

Thanks

Comment: What type of characters is this returning?

Comment: Before `// echoing JSON response `, what do you get from `print_r($response);`? Is it the expected array, or null?

Comment: @ExecutiveCloser Hi, sorry I'm not sure what you mean, it isn't returning anything at all from "ntmContent" just prints "null" onto the webpage.

Comment: How are you retrieving the response on the front end? Jquery ajax call? Or is the above code right on the same webpage you're running in the browser?

Comment: Add junk data to see if it is returning correctly. $Data = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'catnip');
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode($Data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `json_encode` fails to encode a value, it outputs null.

This is due to the odd characters you made reference too in your post.

`json_encode()` only works with `UTF-8`.

Try like this:

```
$ntmRow["ntmContent"] = utf8_encode($row["ntmContent"]);
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to have done the trick. I am now getting an output with the "odd" characters as unicode like this: locations: \u00a0Site\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 is this the correct type of output I should expect?

Comment: What are the odd chars you mentioned  in your question. What is the charset at the db

Comment: Well the \u00a0 is blank space but the "odd" chars are (I think) Ordinal indicators: º   and Degree symbol: °    . The collation is utf8_general_ci if that helps. Thanks